# gridview formatting

Tags: c#

Can anybody help on this?

I have a grid populated with data from Database.Now to format the grid,I want some columns text alone to made Center(text alignment).How to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewId.Columns[0].ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
```

try this on `page_load` or any where.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for :

```
yourGrid.Columns[yourColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = 
DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```